# Applying same function but different calculations to different lists that has binary columns in loop with lapply

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply

The title can be confusing but I guess it has a simple solution. I have my own function and I want to apply same function to multiple lists that consists of two columns. But I need to do different calculations to each column separately.

**As an example `mydata` is:**

```
    x1   x2   y1   y2   z1  z2
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.8  0.0 8.6
2  8.6  0.0  0.0  7.6  1.6 1.4
3 11.2  7.8  3.4  1.2  7.6 0.0
4  8.4  7.6 21.4 10.2 23.6 0.0
5  0.0  1.2  1.8  7.0  3.2 0.0
6  0.0 10.2  1.4  0.0  0.0 0.0

mydata<-structure(list(x1 = c(0, 8.6, 11.2, 8.4, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 0, 
7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2), y1 = c(0, 0, 3.4, 21.4, 1.8, 1.4), y2 = c(7.8, 
7.6, 1.2, 10.2, 7, 0), z1 = c(0, 1.6, 7.6, 23.6, 3.2, 0), z2 = c(8.6, 
1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2", "z1", "z2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**And `myfun` function is:**

```
        myfun<- function(x) {
  means<-sapply(list(x), function(ss) mean(ss, na.rm = T))
  #my point: vars<-sapply(list(y), function(ss) var(ss, na.rm = T))
  mean<-means[[1]]
  #var<-vars[[1]]
  #lists<-list(mean, var)
  #names(lists) <- c("mean", "var")
  #return(lists)
  lists<-list(mean)    
  names(lists)<-c("mean")
  return(lists)
}
```

I used `#`for parts that will be added later in the `myfun`.

When I tried

`results<-lapply(mydata, myfun)`

I can apply same function and same calculation to each column.

As you see there are 2 columns`(x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2)` for each data `(x, y, z)`.

**What I want is:**

1) Obtaining `means` of first columns `(x1, y1, z1)`

2) Obtaining `variances` of second columns `(x2, y2, z2)`

3) And as output; I want to see results of `mean1`and `var1`for each data under `x`, `y` and `z` lists like:

```
x-> mean1 (mean of x1)
    var1  (var of x2)

y-> mean1 (mean of y1)
    var1  (var of y2)
```

4) Do all these in a loop with `lapply` or `sapply` or with any useful function.

**Notes:**

1) I did not group x1 and x2 under x, y1 and y2 under y. Because If a solution can be found for `mydata` form, it would be more useful for me. But if it is necessary I can group them separately.

2) `myfun` function is finding means of 6 columns now. I have indicated the additional parts that will be used to calculate variances of second columns with `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider assigning your groups first, then iterate off this with `lapply`. In fact use `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` for a named list.

```
grps <- unique(gsub("[0-9]", "", colnames(mydata)))
# [1] "x" "y" "z"

myfun <- function(grp)
             list(mean = mean(mydata[,paste0(grp, 1)]),
                  variance = var(mydata[,paste0(grp, 2)]))  

mean_var_list <- sapply(grps, myfun, simplify = FALSE)    

mean_var_list
# $x
# $x$mean
# [1] 4.7
# 
# $x$variance
# [1] 20.87467
# 
# $y
# $y$mean
# [1] 4.666667
# 
# $y$variance
# [1] 16.53467
# 
# $z
# $z$mean
# [1] 6
# 
# $z$variance
# [1] 11.85067
```

Or use the default, `simplify=TRUE` and return a matrix.

```
mean_var_mat <- sapply(grps, myfun)

mean_var_mat
#          x        y        z       
# mean     4.7      4.666667 6       
# variance 20.87467 16.53467 11.85067
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. But I have another question. For my calculations I will import data named 2005,2006.. etc. And for a session I will import 14 years data (from 2005 to 2018). What should I do for this kind naming?

Comment: Please ask a new question with all necessary details including sample data, current attempted code, and desired results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by splitting the dataframe to create a list of dataframes with 2 columns. 
At the point you can use `lapply` or `map_dfr` to apply the function `mean_var` to each of the elements of the list.
The advantage of `map_dfr` is that it return a dataframe, binding the rows of the function output.

```
library(purrr)

my_data_l <- split.default(mydata, rep(1:3, each = 2))

mean_var <- function(x) {
    list(mean = mean(x[,1]), var = var(x[,2]))
}

map_dfr(my_data_l, mean_var)
```

Comment: A little explanation can help new and future useRs. And why `map_dfr` when `lapply` could work? Lightweight is the best weight!

Comment: Good point, I will edit the answer. Indeed ```lapply``` would work too, ```map_dfr``` is convenient because it returns a dataframe by binding the rows of the output of the function

Comment: By the way, your solution takes assumptions on column ordering. What if it were `x2 y2 z2 x1 y1 z1`? Maybe a sort is needed?

Comment: Yes, that is a good point too. In that case I would ```split``` by columns names as shown here in the second [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297089/how-to-split-data-frame-by-column-names-in-r)

Comment: I am appreciate you both. Solutions will be useful for even further studies.